# Why does this RF PCB have small holes in the ground polygon?

Tags: pcb-design, rf, pcb-antenna, ground-plane, lora

I usually pay attention to RF PCBs.

This shape is like a hole, but it is not, the ground surface is used in the form.

What is the purpose of making these holes?

How can I make them easily with the EAGLE PCB design program?

The PCB is inside of the [E70 433NW14S](https://www.cdebyte.com/products/E70-433NW14S) LoRa module from Ebyte.

[image]

Comment: I think that is just a GND via. Why do you think it is anything other than a GND via?

Answer (score 3):

The space between copper planes can act as waveguides for RF frequencies. It makes trace impedence changes, and signal losses.

To cut such waveguide effect, put vias, which is essentially a copper cylinder.

When the distances between vias are small enough compared to wavelength, the board is like continuous copper material, instead of waveguide.

Comment: thanks for answer how to add with eagle software?